# How can I convert a number in an external file into a integer , in python

Tags: python, type-conversion

I have an external file with the number `0`

to convert this I write:

```
file1 = open("example.txt", "r")
number = int(file1)
file1.close()
```

however when I run this code I get an error saying `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: '_io.TextIOWrapper' and 'int'`

So is there any way to convert a number in a file and then make it usable in your code?

Comment: ``file1`` is a file IO object,maybe you need to use `int(file1.read())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *read* the file:

```py
with open("example.txt", "r") as file1:
    content = file1.read()
    number = int(content.rstrip())  # drop the trailing newline
```

Comment: `int(...)` takes care of the newline, no need to strip it before.